# Umbraco with bespoke application

Tags: umbraco

For the my project I am currently umbraco platform as CMS to work with other Bispoke (custom) application that is going to be developed in MVC3. The scope of the project roughtly is as follows:

1) Product Download & Deployment (Bispoke)
2) Product Documentation (CMS)
3) Suport (tickts & its workflow cycle) (Bispoke) 
4) Blogs (CMS)

My question is what is the best approach to use Umbraco to integrate it with Bispoke apps? There will be some functionalities which will be shared between CMS and Bispoke apps.So I would like to get these two under one roof.

Any idea how to achive this?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a broad question so it's hard to answer definitively.

However there are some areas that you need to watch out for.

Firstly take a look at this question which talks about MVC and Umbraco integration:

[MVC and Umbraco integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812552/mvc-and-umbraco-integration).

Next is the question of shared functionality. This is a broader architectural issue. In this case create a business logic layer which can be used by either Umbraco or MVC. That way you can share the functionality and keep the actual MVC and Umbraco portions of the app nicely separated.

The biggest issue will be sharing of things like templates or UI code that could be shared but implemented differently depending on if it is being consumed by MVC or WebForms.

It's rather hard to be any more specific.